# Create a connection between 2 phones

Tags: java, android, android-networking

I would like to make a connection between 2 phones, defined as phone A and phone B.

A asks for B's location, and then B generates its location and sends it to A.

I know how to generate a location, but how can I create a connection between A and B? Is a database required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

generally you will need a server in the middle way. if you want to finish the job without a server, you have to make one of the phone to be a server, but for now carriers block all incoming connections, so your phones cannot reach each other. So set up a server, and let 2 phones connect to it, then transmit the location data.

Comment: did not know that, can you provide a document link, I need to learn more. ty in advance.

Comment: But how phone B will know that phone A is asking for a location? I need something like interface(onBundle() or something like that).

Comment: @bluebrain read about NAT.

Comment: @Imri you need to implement that logic on your server and in your application protocol.

Comment: But how can I create this connection I still don't understand.. let's say that my interface has a method named onLocationRequested() how do I execute it from the other phone? I guess the only way is to create by my self this connection. I know that on a windows application I use the socket class so which one I should use in android platform?

Comment: generally the server should do most of the work, two clients should just report and receive info.

Comment: you can send it to server, then server forward it to the other phone via socket etc, then take action based on received location info

Comment: How the phone that needs to generate locations will know when to start? by this way you suggested the only way I figure out is to connect to the server every x time and check if it needs to generate.

Comment: x and y should keep the connection as long as the app is open.  If X needs the location info of Y, it just send the query to the server, server then forward to Y, Y provide the required info to X via server

Comment: Ok sounds good! Theoretical I understand but how do I implement this connection between x and y?

Comment: at server side, use ServerSocket(port) to listen to a port. At the client side, use Socket(ip,port) to establish a connection with server, you have to design your own protocol to realize the communication link between x and y with a server in the middle.

Comment: But the phone ip's doesn't change when they use the wifi and move between networks?or it doesn't matters

Comment: The mobile ip protocol should take care of this issue itself. The initial IP to establish the connection can be achieved by the dynamic domain

Comment: Ok so just to be sure. It's a simple client/server connection as I do with java on pc programs?

Comment: yes, you can use java to right the server